# Convert ID to class name not working so that I can use it multiple time

Tags: javascript

I have a code pen code. I need to convert the output `document.getElementById("preview");` to class rather than ID. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Code Link : https://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/YWadbB

```
"use strict";
function dragNdrop(event) {
    var fileName = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
    var previewImg = document.createElement("img");
    previewImg.setAttribute("src", fileName);
    preview.innerHTML = "";
    preview.appendChild(previewImg);
}
function drag() {
    document.getElementById('uploadFile').parentNode.className = 'draging dragBox';
}
function drop() {
    document.getElementById('uploadFile').parentNode.className = 'dragBox';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByClassName` and pass class name as parameter.

```
var preview = document.getElementsByClassName(Class_Name);
```